# Two redirects with one IIS site using Umbraco

Tags: iis-7, umbraco6

Umbraco v6.

I have one Umbraco installation with two sites. Second site was added under the "Culture and Hostnames" options.

Under Site 1 Culture and Hostnames is empty but controlled by IIS. Under Site 2 Culture and Hostnames has `http://site2.com`

```
When a user navigates to http://site1.com they reach site 1.

When a user navigates to http://site2.com they reach site 2.
```

So all works as expected.

Is there anyway to add canonical domains so that

```
http://site2.com changes to http://www.site2.com

http://site1.com changes to http://www.site1.com
```

Note the www for each URL.

Remember there is 1 IIS site 1 Umbraco installation and 2 sites in this 1 installation which point to two different websites.

Is this possible to keep the functionality as is but with the changes mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the IIS Rewrite module.
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

You'll just need to write regular expressions to target each of your domains.

e.g (untested).

```
<rule name="Redirect From Site1" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site1.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.site1.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect From Site2" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site2.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.site2.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I noticed i could use the GUI to Add Rule(s). Could i use this to do the above, if yes then do you know which options i need to select? I just want to avoid any minor errors that i may not notice if typing this into the web.config

Comment: The GUI does just publish the XML as above. You'd have to would with an Inbound Blank Rule, but I don't know as it will be any less error prone as you'll still need to enter your Regex's for example.